# Tooltip with ng-messages with in-place error

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to display tooltip for the field when in place error is occured for field. 
If ng-message is "required" then tooltip should display "You did not enter a field" when error is cleared then tooltip should not display anything. Again if ng-message is "maxlength" then tooltip should display "Your field is too long".
This is my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8quYxPBHwxTaysHk2yEX?p=preview)
index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngMessages-directive-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-messages.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngMessagesExample">
  <form name="myForm">
  <label>
    Enter your name:
    <input type="text"
           name="myName"
           ng-model="name"

           ng-maxlength="5"
           required 
           data-toggle="tooltip" title="You did not enter a field!"
           />
  </label>
  <pre>myForm.myName.$error = {{ myForm.myName.$error | json }}</pre>

  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:red" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>

    <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngMessagesExample', ['ngMessages']);


})(window.angular);
```

Any idea how to add tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtFel13n0V6uQmtmS6M8?p=preview) as follows:

In the controller I modified the showerror function:

```
$scope.showerror = function() {
  console.log(myForm.myName);
  if ($scope.myForm.myName.$error) {
    if ($scope.myForm.myName.$error.required == true) {
      $scope.message = "You did not enter a field";
    } else if ($scope.myForm.myName.$error.maxlength == true) {
      $scope.message = "Your field is too long";
    }
  } else {
    $scope.message = "hi";
  }
};
```

Hope this helps.